# Uniform continuity of $\sqrt{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know that there are questions about it but I want to have a clue before I look at the answers.

So can someone give me a clue to how can I prove that:

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{x}\sin \frac{1}{x}
$$

at $(0,\infty)$

Has uniform continuity?

Note: I didn't learn about differentiability yet.

*EDIT:

Using daruma answer:

1. We will extend the continuity of $f$ to $[0, \infty]$, but showing that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0) = 0$ so $f$ is also continous at $0$:

We will use hiene and look at the function as multiplication of 2 series.

$f$ is built from a serie that goes to $0$ at $x \to 0$: $\sqrt{x}$ multiply by a bounded serie $\displaystyle \sin \frac{1}{x}$ so the serie goes to $0$ so is the function $f$.

So the function is continuous at $[0, \infty)$

2. Showing that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$ that will allow us to say, that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x,y > R: |f(x)|, |(f(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, therfore, $\forall \delta > 0,$ at $[R, \infty)$, if $|x-y| < \delta$: $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$.

Therfore, $f$ has uniform continuity at $[R, \infty)$

Now, by Cantor theorom, that if $f$ is continious at a closed interval $[a,b]$ it is also uniformly continious at that interval we conclude that $f$ is uniformly continious at $[0,R]$ as a multiplication of continious functions.

Making a union of the two intervals, we get that $f$ has uniform continuity at $[0 ,\infty)$, particularly, at $(0, \infty)$, as needed.

I would like to hear if you have notes or corrections if i didnt get something right.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Which term dominates the behaviour of $\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: Actually, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$. The $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ term dominates. Can you show why this is true? (Hint: $|\sin\theta|\leqslant |\theta|$)

Comment: $0 \leq \lim_{x \to \infty}{|\sqrt{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}|} \leq \lim_{x \to \infty}{|\sqrt{x} \frac{1}{x}|} = \lim_{x \to \infty}{|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}|} = 0$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now, can you determine the behavior near zero?

Comment: at $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ i think i can say its a serie that goes to $0$ which is the $\sqrt{x}$ multiply by a serie that is bounded which is the $sin$ therefore its going to zero: $\lim_{x \to 0^+}|\sqrt{x}sin \frac{1}{x}| = 0$

Comment: maman 15 in open university? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we can separate the $[0,\infty)$ into two parts, a closed bounded interval and a half-line.

We can show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$ (This is because $|\sin\frac{1}{x}|\leqslant \frac{1}{x}$ and so we can compare the limit to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x}\cdot \frac{1}{x}=0$)

So for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $R>0$ such that if $x>R$, then we have $|f(x)|<\epsilon/2$. I hope it is clear that on $[R,\infty)$, we can choose any $\delta>0$ so that $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Check that $f(x)$ can be extended to a continuous function to $0$. 
Now on $[0,R]$, as $f$ is continuous, the function is uniformly continuous. (Continuous functions on closed bounded intervals are uniformly continuous)

Now you can piece these two pieces to show uniform continuity on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: I edited my post and tried to write it all down as a complete proof. Thank you for the help. I changed alittle bit here and there, so if you see anything need correction i would like to hear. Btw, i have hard time understanding how can i ask questions that im stuck at and getting a hint and not full answers, because in the end i should get use to prove myself, as i have an exam.

Comment: And im not that sure that i understood what u said at "I hope it is clear that on..." i tried to write something that will explain it, correct me if i was wrong.

Comment: I think your answer is fine but you will perhaps need to be a bit more explicit with your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ if you are doing this as part of your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$. Since the limit exists as $x\to 0$ from the right, the function can be extended to a continuous function in $[0,\infty)$. Now, in the interval $[0,1]$ the function is therefore uniformly continuous by Cantor's theorem. In the interval $[1,\infty)$ it is uniformly continuous because the derivative is bounded. I did notice you said you haven't learned about differentiability yet, but to prove the uniform continuity of the function in $[a,\infty)$ would be quite complicated without the notion of the derivative

If you don't want, or can't, or not allowed to use differentiability, you may try and prove the following proposition:

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function in $[a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$. Assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't learn about differentiation yet, i can't use it.

Comment: Oh, i asked how do i prove it, someone edited my question as if i didnt know that.... thanks anyway

Comment: I dont understand why you are laughing at me, against my religion?, i said that i can't use it but thank you, thats all.

Comment: I apologise. I should not have said that. btw, just so you know, we both have the same religion.

Comment: Nevermind, its ok, thanks for the answer again